# Discount(coupon code) automatically removing in checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3.p1, magento-shipping

I am using WebShopApps_MatrixRate extension for listing shipping methods in checkout based on "Order Subtotal vs. Destination".

But I am facing an strange problem that coupon code(discount) automatically removing in checkout page.
Coupon code applying in checkout/cart and also showing discount amount but when after filling address fields in checkout page coupon code and discount automatically removed.

Please help me if you have faced same problem.

I am using Magento 2.4.3 -p1.

Comment: Check what conditions are there in your shopping cart price rule, it might be because id doesn't satisfying any condition after adding address.